# Pandas - find nearest dates between two DataFrames without loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the nearest previous date using two separate DataFrames.  I've actually got the code to do it, but it uses a `for` loop, which I would rather not use, especially as my actual DataFrames will be considerably larger than the following snippet:

```
date_x = pd.to_datetime(['1/15/2015','2/14/2015','3/16/2015','4/15/2015','5/15/2015','6/14/2015','7/14/2015'])
date_y = pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2015','3/1/2015','6/14/2015','8/1/2015'])

dfx = pd.DataFrame({'date_x':date_x})
dfy = pd.DataFrame({'date_y':date_y})

z_list = []
for x in range(dfx['date_x'].count()):
    z_list.append(dfy['date_y'][dfy['date_y'] <= dfx['date_x'][x]].max())

dfx['date_z'] = z_list
```

yields...

```
      date_x     date_z
0 2015-01-15 2015-01-01
1 2015-02-14 2015-01-01
2 2015-03-16 2015-03-01
3 2015-04-15 2015-03-01
4 2015-05-15 2015-03-01
5 2015-06-14 2015-06-14
6 2015-07-14 2015-06-14
```

which is exactly what I want, but again, I think there is a more pandonic way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [merge_asof()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) method:

NOTE: this method has been added in Pandas v.0.19.0

```
In [17]: pd.merge_asof(dfx, dfy, left_on='date_x', right_on='date_y')
Out[17]:
      date_x     date_y
0 2015-01-15 2015-01-01
1 2015-02-14 2015-01-01
2 2015-03-16 2015-03-01
3 2015-04-15 2015-03-01
4 2015-05-15 2015-03-01
5 2015-06-14 2015-06-14
6 2015-07-14 2015-06-14
```

Comment: That's absurd.  Thank you!  I feel a little ridiculous since this was the second time `merge_asof()` was mentioned to me today, but I need to get clubbed over the head a few times apparently.  Great function.

Comment: If the nearest is actually after that date, it seems to still go to the previous.  I guess it just reads my mind.  And I'm ok with that.

Comment: Great answer :-).

Comment: @MaxU happy holidays

Comment: @piRSquared, merry Xmas and a Happy New year! :-)