# Pandas: Merge on exact ID and closest date

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge two Pandas dataframes on two columns.  One column has a unique identifier that could be used to simply `.merge()` the two dataframes.  However, the second column merge would actually use `.merge_asof()` because it would need to find the *closest* date, not an exact date match.

There is a similar question here: [Pandas Merge on Name and Closest Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614474/pandas-merge-on-name-and-closest-date), but it was asked and answered nearly three years ago, and `merge_asof()` is a much newer addition.

I asked a similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317051/pandas-find-nearest-dates-between-two-dataframes-without-loop) question a couple months ago, but the solution only needed to use `merge_asof()` without any exact matches required.

In the interest of including some code, it would look something like this:

`df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on=['ID','date_time'], right_on=['ID','date_time'])`

where the `ID`'s will match exactly, but the `date_time`'s will be "near matches".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm familiar with the guidelines, but those who know what I'm asking don't need anything more than what I've written.

Comment: Could you please post your solution? I am facing the same issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider merging first on the `ID` and then run a [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to return highest *date_time* from first dataframe on matched IDs less than the current row *date_time* from second dataframe.

```
# INITIAL MERGE (CROSS-PRODUCT OF ALL ID PAIRINGS)
mdf = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ID'])

def f(row):
    col = mdf[(mdf['ID'] == row['ID']) & 
              (mdf['date_time_x'] < row['date_time_y'])]['date_time_x'].max()
    return col

# FILTER BY MATCHED DATES TO CONDITIONAL MAX
mdf = mdf[mdf['date_time_x'] ==  mdf.apply(f, axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

This assumes you want to keep all rows of df2 (i.e., *right join*). Simply flip _x / _y suffixes for *left join*.

Comment: Parfait - I think I actually solved my own problem and I believe adding the kwarg: `by = 'ID'` was the key.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not quite sure of your answer or how I helped. Feel free to answer your own question for future readers and wait a few days to accept your own. I was waiting to hear response of how this solution did not work. Note that this only picks max date mirroring `asof` (not nearest).

Answer (score 0):

The current solution would work on a small dataset but if you have hundreds of rows... I'm afraid not.

So, what you want to do is as follows:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on = 'date_time', by = 'ID', direction = 'nearest')
```